# Computing separate tfidf scores for two different columns using sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm trying to compute the similarity between a set of queries and a set a result for each query.  I would like to do this using tfidf scores and cosine similarity.  The issue that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to generate a tfidf matrix using two columns (in a pandas dataframe).  I have concatenated the two columns and it works fine, but it's awkward to use since it needs to keep track of which query belongs to which result.  How would I go about calculating a tfidf matrix for two columns at once?  I'm using pandas and sklearn.

Here's the relevant code:

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', min_df = 0)
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(df_all['search_term'] + df_all['product_title']) # This line is the issue
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names()
```

I'm trying to pass df_all['search_term'] and df_all['product_title'] as arguments into tf.fit_transform.  This clearly does not work since it just concatenates the strings together which does not allow me to compare the search_term to the product_title.  Also, is there maybe a better way of going about this?

Comment: You need to add a space in like this `df_all['search_term'] + " " + df_all['product_title']` other wise you might be combining the first word of the product with the last word of the search

Comment: also you don't need `analyzer=word`, since this is the default value

Comment: That line in my code is not what I want, I would like the terms and products to be separate so that I can compute cosine similarity between the search and the product.

Comment: i know, i'm just saying that if you are trying to combine them together you need to add the space in, you will need this sometime in the future

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've made a good start by just putting all the words together; often a simple pipeline such as this will be enough to produce good results. You can build more complex feature processing pipelines using `pipeline` and `preprocessing`. Here's how it would work for your data:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion, Pipeline

df_all = pd.DataFrame({'search_term':['hat','cat'], 
                       'product_title':['hat stand','cat in hat']})

transformer = FeatureUnion([
                ('search_term_tfidf', 
                  Pipeline([('extract_field',
                              FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x['search_term'], 
                                                  validate=False)),
                            ('tfidf', 
                              TfidfVectorizer())])),
                ('product_title_tfidf', 
                  Pipeline([('extract_field', 
                              FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x['product_title'], 
                                                  validate=False)),
                            ('tfidf', 
                              TfidfVectorizer())]))]) 

transformer.fit(df_all)

search_vocab = transformer.transformer_list[0][1].steps[1][1].get_feature_names() 
product_vocab = transformer.transformer_list[1][1].steps[1][1].get_feature_names()
vocab = search_vocab + product_vocab

print(vocab)
print(transformer.transform(df_all).toarray())

['cat', 'hat', 'cat', 'hat', 'in', 'stand']

[[ 0.          1.          0.          0.57973867  0.          0.81480247]
 [ 1.          0.          0.6316672   0.44943642  0.6316672   0.        ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm trying to figure this out, but I can't seem to figure out what it's returning.  When I run it, I'm not getting a tfidf matrix, is it giving me something else?  Also, is it supposed to be accessing df_all?  It doesn't seem like it's being referenced at all...

Comment: I've added an example calculation to hopefully make things clearer. to be honest, i can't work out exactly what variant of tf-idf is being used, i think it might be using log-frequencies even though in the docs is says it doesn't)

Comment: this guy's put some notes together which may clarify things https://github.com/rasbt/pattern_classification/blob/master/machine_learning/scikit-learn/tfidf_scikit-learn.ipynb

Comment: I would recommend using traditional functions over lambda, as lambda can cause unexpected behavior. See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9467

Comment: I would recommend also using a transformer like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52703546/7927776