# Scikit Learn - Combining output of TfidfVectorizer and OneHotEncoder - dimensionality

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scikit-learn

I am currently developing a machine learning algorithm for ticket classification that combines a Title, Description and Customer name together to predict what team a ticket should be assigned to but have been stuck for the past few days.

Title and description are both free text and so I am passing them through TfidfVectorizer. Customer name is a category, for this I am using OneHotEncoder. I want these to work within a pipeline so have them being joined with a column transformer where I can pass in an entire dataframe and have it be processed.

```
file = "train_data.csv"
train_data= pd.read_csv(train_file)
string_features = ['Title', 'Description']
string_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()))
categorical_features = ['Customer']
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('OHE', preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()))
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('str', string_transformer, string_features), ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)])
clf = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),('clf', SGDClassifier())]
X_train = train_data.drop('Team', axis=1)
y_train = train_data['Team']
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However I get an error: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.

After looking into it, `print(OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_train['Customer']))` on its own returns an error: Expected 2d array got 1d array instead.

I believe that OneHotEncoder is failing as it is expecting an array of arrays (a pandas dataframe), each being length one containing the customer name. But instead is just getting a pandas series. By converting the series to a dataframe with .to_frame() the printed output now seems to match what is outputted by the TfidfVectorizer and the dimensions should match.

**Is there a way I can modify OneHotEncoder in the pipeline so that it accepts the input as it is in 1 dimension? Or is there something I can add to the pipeline that will convert it before it's passed into OneHotEncoder? Am I right in that this is the reason for the error?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in the fact that you're giving two columns to the `TfIdfVectorizer` (which is thus converted to a `DataFrame`). This will not work: `TfIdfVectorizer` expects a list of strings. So an immediate solution (and therefore a check of whether this is in fact the source of the problem), is changing this line to: `string_features = 'Description'`. Note this is *not* a list, it just a string. Therefore the `Series` is passed to the `TfIdfVectorizer`, and not the `DataFrame`.

If you would like to combine both string columns, you could either

- concatanenate the strings, so you keep one column (which is the easiest), or
- Fit two different `TfIdfVectorizers`, which is more complex but might perform better.  See for instance [Computing separate tfidf scores for two different columns using sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731813/computing-separate-tfidf-scores-for-two-different-columns-using-sklearn)

Should this not solve your problem, I would advise you to share some sample data so we can actually test what is happening.

I believe the difference between your perceived error and the actual pipeline lies in the fact that you're giving it `X_train['Customer']` (again a `Series`), but in the actual pipeline you're giving it `X_train[['Customer']]` (a `DataFrame`).

Comment: Thank you so much you were absolutely correct. Thank you for your insight and quick response!

Comment: Check this answer for a complete example https://stackoverflow.com/a/54704747/7358899